# Improper Cast of integer, how am I doing this wrong?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, int

I'm failing at properly casting an integer. How am I doing this wrong?

```
void spellCheck(char article[], char dictionary[]) {
    char articleWord[50];
    char dictionaryWord[50];
    int articleLength = articleLength(char article[]);
    removePunc(article);
    toLower(article);
    lowerDictionary(dictionary);
    nextArticleWord(article, articleWord, articleLength, dictionary);

}
```

Error occurs at:

```
int articleLength = articleLength(char article[]);
```

and another error occurs when nextArticleWord() is declared:

```
void nextArticleWord(char article[], 
char articleWord[],  
int articleLength, 
char dictionaryWord[], 
char dictionary[])
```

Probably related to the improper cast...

Full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/bTrhrXzt).

Comment: `articleLength` is both the name of a local variable and a function? If that's a function call, that's improper syntax for passing an argument.

Comment: change to `int articleLength = articleLength(article);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY When I do that it says "called object 'articleLength' is not a function."

Comment: @yano So yeah I think you're correct. I'm not sure how else to pass it though.

Comment: Ah So change variable  name. E.g `int article_length = articleLength(article);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY When I do this it gives me a conflicting type error for the `nextArticleWord()` function. Its like if I don't give it the same name that function just screws up. Furthermore I tried removing that line completely cause in my head the `nextArticleWord()` will just call the global `int artcleLength()`. Once I do this it for some reason doesn't like that I scan `article` with `int articleLength()`. its like one problem leads to the same problem as the others *desksmash*

Comment: `nextArticleWord` : It is different arguments in the definition and the prototype.

Comment: Holy crap I can't believe I didn't catch that... clearly I've been staring at this code for too long. @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local integer variable `articleLength` seems in conflict with the a global function using the same name.

The function `articleLength(char[])` is not being properly called.

Try this:

```
void spellCheck(char article[], char dictionary[]) {
    char articleWord[50];
    char dictionaryWord[50];
    int articleLen = articleLength(article);
    removePunc(article);
    toLower(article);
    lowerDictionary(dictionary);
    nextArticleWord(article, articleWord, articleLen, dictionary);
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this same thing with a different variable name, but whenever I did I got a type conflict error with my 'nextArticleWord()' when the function is made.

Comment: @RyanTibbetts  prototype :  `void nextArticleWord(char article[], char articleWord[],  int articleLength, char dictionary[]);` but definition : `void nextArticleWord(char article[], char articleWord[],  int articleLength, char dictionaryWord[], char dictionary[]){`

Answer (score -1):

try this:

> int articleLength = strlen(article);
>
> or
>
> int articleLength = sizeof(article);

hope can help you!